# PHP Dependency Injection when multiple types of databases are used in the same class

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, design-patterns

I'm working on a very unorganized (no tests, logic mixed in everywhere) PHP application. I started reading the book [Modernizing Legacy Applications In PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/131210063X) and am now in the position where I need to replace `global` variables.

In my case we have both MySQL and MongoDB mixed heavily throughout the application using global variables: `$database` for MySQL and `$mongo` for MongoDB. I'm wondering what the best way to inject both of these databases would be. Most examples (in the book and elsewhere) have something like this:

```
class Database {
    public function __construct() {}
}

class MySQL extends Database {
    private $mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        $default_options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        // get config from file
        $this->mysql = new PDO(...);
    }

    public function get_instance() { return $this->mysql; }

}

class MongoDB extends Database {

    private $mongodb;  

    public function __construct() {
        // get config from file
        $mongodb = new MongoClient(...);
    }

    public function get_instance() { return $this->mongodb; }
}

class User {

    private $database = null;
    private $table = "users";

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

}

// In another file:
$user = new User(new \Database\MySQL);
```

That's cool, but the problem I'm having is, when `User` stores its attributes like `name`,`email`, `id`, etc. in MySQL, and it stores something else like `user_type` in Mongo (obviously its more than this but I'm just giving an easy example), than how does dependency injection work?

Do I have to pass in two `Database` classes to the constructor?

Do I have a `set_database` function that I have to keep switching between when I want to make a call?

```
class User {

    private $database = null;
    private $table = "users";

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function get_user() {
        $first_set = $this->database->run('select * from users',[]);
        $this->database->set_database(new \Database\MongoDB);
        $second_set = $this->database->run('users',[]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how this would work, and would continue working if other developers added databases that had to be called in the `User` class (like Redis for example).

Comment: The `new \Database\MongoDB` smells.  DI should remove that from the class.

Comment: get_instance method above smells like a singleton (which is another global).  Two globals $mongo and $mysql are easy to grok.  Are passing these into constructors a burden?

Comment: @Progrock I think OP is asking IF passing these two dependencies into the constructor is the way to go or should they do something else.

Comment: If the two are passed into the constructor separately the code is more explicit.

Comment: I think you're trying to over-abstract things here.  I notice you have classes for both MySQL and Mongo, even though they are very different beasts.  You might want to limit yourself to just relational DBs, or just NoSQL DBs.  Also, you might want to look into using interfaces as an aid to dependency injection.  An interface says only what you need to implement, not how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sub>**Warning**: the following post contains use of Singleton antipattern as a temporary tool in refactoring of large scale clusterfuck</sub>

I think you might have missed an important part of refactoring (or at least, focused on the wrong part). You should be aiming for as specific final result in this process. A specific architectural structure that you want to see (and that all your co-workers agree on). Right now you seem to just aimlessly trying to *"make it less shit"*.

#### In the beginning ...

You immediate milestone seems to be *"get rid of global variables"*. So, focus on that. Attempting to in the same time switch to fully dependency-injected structure will confuse things and increase the chance you fail.

Instead you should start by switching to registry (you could use singletons as a temporary step, but those are harder to clean out later).

So the code that looked like:

```
class Foobar {
    function something() {
        global $database; 
        $database->query('SELECT ... blah');
    }
}
```

Would be rewritten as:

```
class Foobar {
    function something() {
        $database = Registry::getDatabase(); 
        $database->query('SELECT ... blah');
    }
}
```

This would solve one specific problem: getting rid of global variables.

#### Second step

When that is done, you can start working on switching to dependency-injections. But not by adding typehints. That would require huge rewrites with a large "impact surface" (easy to break something).

Instead you start introducing DI container, but only for the parts, that were previously using singletons or registry. You create a singleton, that holds the instance of DI container (you basically use it as a **service locator** antipattern), and the code gets rewritten as:

```
class Foobar {
    function something() {
        $database = Locator::get('database'); 
        $database->query('SELECT ... blah');
    }
}
```

This is how procedural code (that also include static-only classes) can be refactored in this direction.

#### Third step

Next you need to start doing the OOP thing. You need to have those (previously global) variables to be moved to shared withing the class instance:

```
class Foobar {
    private $database;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->database = Locator::get('database'); 
    }

    public function something() {
        $this->database->query('SELECT ... blah');
    }
}
```

#### Fourth step

And only now you can actually move to using actual dependencies in the constructors.

```
class Foobar {
    private $database;

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database; 
    }

    public function something() {
        $this->database->query('SELECT ... blah');
    }
}
```

You also need to replace every case, where you have: `$thing = new Foobar();` with
`$thing = Locator::get('foobar');`, and then repeat the **step 3** for the class in which the `Foobar` was used, till you reach the bootstrap.

#### End of cycle

When you have completed the migration process, you stop using the `Locator` singleton wrapper in the bootstrap file and switch to using the actual DI container instance.

You might also have noticed that each of the steps can be performed, while new features are also being added to the codebase, because at no point it requires touching large swaths of code in unrelated location. Migration of each class can be done separately without breaking the functionality of the application as whole.

### But

(and this is a big but).

From the piece of code that you showed, you would have another problem, that you need to solve. It is very likely, that your `User` class is actually implementing [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) antipattern. So, when you are do with getting rid of globals, one of the next possible steps would be separating the persistence logic from business logic and switching to [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern. For further reading on that I will just spam three older posts of mine: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146145/727208), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946409/727208) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859936/727208).

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I am wondering though, in this case, how does `Registry::getDatabase()` know which database to return (mysql or mongo)? And in your example with the `Locator` would I get mongo with `Locator::get('mongo')`? For the locator, is it just easier to grep for that pattern and replace it eventually, over replacing the `Registry`

Comment: No, the intention was that you would create `Registry::getDatabase()` and `Registry::getMango()`. Also, that step would let you add deferred initialization, by using similar approach to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208), if you need it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you again!

Comment: What you have to keep in mind is that throughout this process you would be replacing a bad practice will slightly less bad. Both registry pattern and service locator are considered to be anti-patterns. And only when you finally switch to DI container will your code be rig of those anti-patterns.

Comment: Each step lets you have deploy-able code.Which is why I did not recommend starting with service locator, Especially since it will require some additional coding to make a static wrapper for a DI container and you will also need to set up that DI container. If you decide to use Symfony's standalone container (does not require the rest of the framework), then you can try picking up this example to see how it can be set up: https://github.com/teresko/blank

Comment: If the eventual aim is DI, then why not keep the globals firstly, but move global lines to the constructors and initialise them as properties.  Like your third step?  Globals are initialised upfront currently, so I don't really see any gains of the in-between steps (locator and registry).

Comment: Because that's not how global variables are used. It's highly possible that some code does not even have an object, but instead is inside random function or "static classes".  By moving the the process to a Registry you gain a control over **where the variables are accessed. You also gain an option "initialize on first use". Locator is intended for setting up all the infrastructure for the future switch to DI Containers. It lets you safely test your setup in first staging and then production environment. It also lets you to get rid global configuration.

Comment: @Progrock when you work in huge and old codebase, you can't make large drastic changes at one fail swoop. The introduction of features has to be gradual. Primarily to make sure, that the codebase is still stable. But with a large codebase you also have a large team, where not everyone is up to date. You need to convince your co-workers (or even so called "senior developers), that each thing you introduce has a tangible benefit. And each improvement has to be small enough so that you can't be told, that "there is no time".

Comment: I agree with a piecemeal approach.  But just in time initialisation is a nice to have, and may not be a requirement here (or rather it is besides the point).  Thanks for the walk-through and comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can abstract it to multiple layers but first step would be something like this:

```php
class PdoConfig {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $dsn;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct(string $dsn, string $username = null, string $password = null, array $options = []) {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public static function constructFromConfigurationFile(string $file_path): self {
        //read data from config
        return new self($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }

    public function getDsn(): string {
        return $this->dsn;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getOptions(): array {
        return $this->options;
    }
}

class MongoDbConfig {

    // pattern as in PDOOptions
}

class Database {

    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $pdo;

    /**
     * @var MongoClient
     */
    private $mongo_db;

    public function __construct(PdoConfig $pdo_config, MongoDbConfig $mongo_db_config) {
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            $pdo_config->getDsn(),
            $pdo_config->getUsername(),
            $pdo_config->getPassword(),
            $pdo_config->getOptions()
        );

        $this->mongo_db = new MongoClient(...);
    }

    public function getPdo(): PDO {
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    public function getMongoDb(): MongoClient {
        return $this->mongo_db;
    }

}

class User {

    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    private $database;

    private $table = 'users';

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

}

$database = new Database(
    PdoConfig::constructFromConfigurationFile('/path/to/pdo_config'),
    MongoDbConfig::constructFromConfigurationFile('/path/to/mongo_config')
);

// In another file:
$user = new User($database);
```

But it's only the first step. Second one could be some single class (like factory) that instantiates `User` objects passing the `Database` object to it. But surely you can build more and more layers of abstraction (config parsers, file readers, data mappers and so on). Dependency injector could become handy then - personally, I like [Auryn](https://packagist.org/packages/rdlowrey/auryn).